# Ordenar Tanto por Data de publicação quanto por Atualização

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Galera estou configurando uma Index e estou tentando fazer o seguinte... 
Eu vou ter esse 'mini destaque' e no momento consegui ordenar ele por apenas DATA, porem algumas vezes a noticia será atualizada e eu gostaria que essa noticia subisse baseado TBM na data de modificação. Aqui o codigo para vocês analisar !

```
<div class="news-wrap" id="news-section">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <section class="news">
                                    <h4 class="section-title">
                                        <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/eventos-e-lazer') ?>" target="_self">Eventos</a>
                                    </h4>
                                    <?php

                                    $posts = get_posts(array(
                                        'numberposts'   => 4,
                                        'post_type'     => 'post',
                                        'category_name' => 'eventos-e-lazer',
                                        'orderby'       => 'date',
                                        'order'         => 'DESC'
                                    ));

                                    $count = 0;

                                    foreach ($posts as $post):

                                        setup_postdata($post);

                                        if($count == 0): ?>
                                            <article class="news-destaque">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                    <figure>
                                                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                    </figure>
                                                    <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                                </a>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </div>

                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                            </article>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <article class="news-reduced">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                            </article>
                                        <?php endif;

                                        $count++;

                                    endforeach; ?>
                                </section>

                                <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/eventos-e-lazer') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Dentro do seu orderby, tente inserir `array( 'date' => 'ASC', 'date_update' => 'ASC' )`

Comment: Talvez esse link possa lhe ajudar https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65769/multiple-orderby-values-in-wp-query

Comment: Funcionar ele está funcionando, apenas fiz uma alteração, 

 o problema que está sumindo com a miniatura da postagem

Comment: Tava analisando as postagens, ele não esta funcionando de acordo com os update e data de publicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se um post foi publicado e não foi modificado, a data de atualização é a mesma data da publicação, então você pode usar simplesmente a data de atualização:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => 4,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'eventos-e-lazer',
    'orderby'       => 'modified',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
));
```

Veja [Order e Orderby Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) na documentação oficial.

Comment: Olha eu tinha Tentado o modified mas na hora que testei acredito que não prestei atenção no funcionamento, mas essa maneira que você citou funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado =)